# Increase the level of dynamic binding with backtick / comma

Tags: lexical-scoping, let-binding

I have a favorite function that contains several levels of `set-process-sentinel` and `lambda` sentinels.  I have been using `lexical-let`, but would like to see if it is possible to use dynamically bound variables using a backtick / comma to penetrate several levels deep.  In my testing, I see that a variable dynamically bound using a backtick / comma only pentetrates a couple of levels before the variable becomes `void`.  Is there a way to increase the levels of penetration when using the backtick?

Example with `lexical-let`:

```lisp
(defun example-lexical-fn ()
"Doc-string"
(interactive)
  (lexical-let* ((test-variable "Hello-world!"))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "process-one" "*one*" "echo" test-variable)
      (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (set-process-sentinel
          (start-process "process-two" "*two*" "echo" test-variable)
          (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
            (start-process "process-three" "*three*" "echo" test-variable)
            (set-process-sentinel
              (start-process "process-four" "*four*" "echo" test-variable)
              (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                (set-process-sentinel
                  (start-process "process-five" "*five*" "echo" test-variable)
                  (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                    (message "test-variable:  %s" test-variable)))))))))))))))
```

The dynamic binding putters-out and the `test-variable` becomes a `void-variable` at the section labeled "process-three".

```lisp
(defun example-dynamic-fn ()
"Doc-string"
(interactive)
  (let* ((test-variable "Hello-world!"))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "process-one" "*one*" "echo" test-variable)
      `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (set-process-sentinel
          (start-process "process-two" "*two*" "echo" ,test-variable)
          `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
            (start-process "process-three" "*three*" "echo" ,test-variable)
            (set-process-sentinel
              (start-process "process-four" "*four*" "echo" ,test-variable)
              `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                (set-process-sentinel
                  (start-process "process-five" "*five*" "echo" ,test-variable)
                  `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                    (message "test-variable:  %s" ,test-variable)))))))))))))))
```

---

Here is the working example based on the helpful answer of zk_phi:  "*Change all backticks to quote (') except for the first one . . . .*"

```lisp
(defun example-dynamic-fn ()
"Doc-string"
(interactive)
  (let ((test-variable "Hello-world!"))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "process-one" "*one*" "echo" test-variable)
      `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (set-process-sentinel
          (start-process "process-two" "*two*" "echo" ,test-variable)
          '(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
            (start-process "process-three" "*three*" "echo" ,test-variable)
            (set-process-sentinel
              (start-process "process-four" "*four*" "echo" ,test-variable)
              '(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                (set-process-sentinel
                  (start-process "process-five" "*five*" "echo" ,test-variable)
                  '(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                    (message "test-variable:  %s" ,test-variable)))))))))))))))
```

Comment: I think you should only need a single backquote.

Comment: Using nested backtick instead of lexical scoping is masochism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many backticks in the expression. If you nest n backticks, then you need n commas before the expression you want to splice.

`highlight-stages` package shows which parts in a expression are quoted (not evaluated), FYI.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to please block and copy my second example, modify it, and post it as a working solution so that I can test and verify that it works as advertised.   Thanks in advance.  :)  Since the example uses `echo` as the executable, it should work on any `*nix` flavored operating system.  The last line that is `(message "test-variable: %s" . . .)` should return "**test-variable:  Hello-world!**" in the `*Messages*` buffer if the solution is indeed the correct answer.  Much appreciated . . .

Comment: Change all backticks to quote (') except for the first one, and it should work :)

Comment: Yes, that does indeed fix the second example -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using backquotes like this is a bad idea: everything within the backquote loses access to lexically-scoped variables, plus it won't be compiled, macros will be expanded late/repeatedly, kittens will suffer, your karma will go down, and then some.

Better do something like

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(defvar my-dynbound-var)

(defun example-dynamic-fn ()
  "Doc-string"
  (interactive)
  (let ((v "Hello World!"))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "process-one" "*one*" "echo" v)
      (lambda (p e)
        (let ((my-dynbound-var v))
          ...
          (set-process-sentinel
            (start-process "process-four" "*four*" "echo" v)
            (lambda (p e)
              (let ((my-dynbound-var v))
                ...))))))))
```

I.e. you re-bind the dynbound variable within each sentinel where you need it, and propagate the value between them via a lexically-scoped var.